# Bigquery column names

Tags: google-bigquery

Does Bigquery accept column name with hyphen (-) example : abc-xyz. My understanding is it will allow to create table with column having hyphen but while writing select statement on those column it will throw an error. Any thoughts

Comment: just put back-ticks around such column name and it will get through

Comment: Thanks . You mean to say in select I can use select abc--xyz from table name in Bigquery and it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the official document from Google Cloud for `column names`.

###### [Column names](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names)

> A column name can contain the letters (a-z, A-Z), numbers (0-9), or underscores (_), and it must start with a letter or underscore. For more flexible column name support, see flexible column names.
> Column names have a maximum length of 300 characters.

However, if you insist on using more complex column names, you may want to check the preview feature `flexible column names`. It covers Unicode, special characters, and so on.

###### [Flexible column names](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#flexible-column-names)

- *Currently `Preview` stage (2023.06)*

```
SELECT
    10 as column_name,
    11 as `column-name`,
    12 as `열: Korean`,  -- Unicode, colon (:), whitespace, English
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. Since we are using DBT for SQL transformation it was failing in unit testing framework so instead of changing unit testing framework we decided to change column name from - to _ and everything it worked.